# Unable to load script. Make sure you're either running a Metro server. [React Native]

Tags: react-native

I know it is a vague title, but I am not sure how else to describe it. I have followed the instructions here (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started), and attempting to run it on an emulator using the react-native cli. It built and installed it, but then said the server was not running. So I started the server first and ran it. Then Gradle failed saying it could not read the file in bbuild\intermediates\transforms\mergeJniLibs\debug\0\lib. So I deleted the debug folder and got it to run, but same red message again. I am not sure what I am missing.

[image: error message]

Comment: Hello, you need to re-start the Metro bundler. 

`react-native start --reset-cache`, after the Metro bundler is running you can run the app with `react-native run-ios/android`

Comment: perfect. Thank you.